drawing a curved custom line in compose
I am new to Android Development and am trying to draw a custom curved line in compose. I am able to draw a straight line but the curved line is not coming as expected.
i have stored the node data as :
Node(name = "a", connections = listOf("b", "c"), startOrEnd = true),
    Node(name = "b", connections = listOf("d"), startOrEnd = false),
    Node(name = "c", connections = listOf("d"), startOrEnd = false),
    Node(name = "d", connections = listOf("e"), startOrEnd = false),
    Node(name = "e", connections = emptyList(), startOrEnd = true)

click here to view the design
    drawLine(
                                start = Offset(
                                    x = sourceCoordinates.x,
                                    y = sourceCoordinates.y
                                ),
                                end = Offset(
                                    x = destinationCoordinates.x,
                                    y = destinationCoordinates.y
                                ),
                                color = Color.Black,
                                strokeWidth = 1.dp.toPx()
                            )```

i know the source node coordinates and the destination node coordinates (it's center coordinates)
 Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .verticalScroll(scrollState)
        .drawBehind {
            for (i in nodes) {
                for (j in 0 until i.connections.size) {
                    val destinationNode = i.connections[j]
                    val sourceCoordinates = i.sourceCoordinates
                    val destinationCoordinates =
                        nodes.find { it.name == destinationNode }?.sourceCoordinates
                    if (sourceCoordinates != null && destinationCoordinates != null) {
                        drawLine(
                            start = Offset(
                                x = sourceCoordinates.x,
                                y = sourceCoordinates.y
                            ),
                            end = Offset(
                                x = destinationCoordinates.x,
                                y = destinationCoordinates.y
                            ),
                            color = Color.Black,
                            strokeWidth = 1.dp.toPx()
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
)

i have drawn the straight line in the draw behind function, i have added the design above but when i use your code im not able to get a curved line. I want to add the curved line function in the drawbehind function as well, is it possible?

import androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.drawIntoCanvas
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun CurvedLineDemo() {
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val sourceCoordinates = Offset(100f, 100f)
        val destinationCoordinates = Offset(300f, 300f)
        
        // Create a Path object
        val path = Path()

        // Move the starting point to the source coordinates
        path.moveTo(sourceCoordinates.x, sourceCoordinates.y)

        // Calculate control points for the curve
        val controlPointX = (sourceCoordinates.x + destinationCoordinates.x) / 2
        val controlPointY = (sourceCoordinates.y + destinationCoordinates.y) / 2 - 100

        // Draw a quadratic Bézier curve to the destination coordinates
        path.quadraticBezierTo(
            controlPointX,
            controlPointY,
            destinationCoordinates.x,
            destinationCoordinates.y
        )

        // Draw the path on the canvas
        drawIntoCanvas { canvas ->
            canvas.drawPath(path, Color.Black)
        }
    }
}


curved line is still not coming
